# Exclude Records in a Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want the value of Loan_Type_Mismatch to be 'Mismatch' for all records where Loan_Type1 <> Loan_Type2 except where Loan_Type1 = 'D1' and Loan_Type2 = 'D0'.  I'm struggling to do this in a CASE statement with SQL Server 2019 and hoping someone can help.

```
CASE 
WHEN 
    Loan_Type1 <> Loan_Type2
    OR (Loan_Type1 = 'D1' AND (Loan_Type2 <> 'D1' AND Loan_Type2 <> 'D0'))          
THEN 'Mismatch'     
ELSE '' END
AS Loan_Type_Mismatch
```

Results I'm getting now

[image]

Desired results

[image]

Comment: Loan_Type1 <> Loan_Type2 and not(loan_type1 = 'D1' and loan_type = 'D0')

Comment: It's a `CASE` *expression*, and a *row*, as an FYI.

Comment: Yes, yes... we all know that a CASE Statement is actually called a CASE expression... I'll still never call it an expression... can't make me :)  Not even in an Interview.

Comment: When the left side of ``OR`` is true then the right won't check.

Comment: You may find it easier to understand if you reverse the logic: `CASE WHEN Loan_Type1 = Loan_Type2 OR (Loan_Type1 = 'D1' AND Loan_Type2 = 'D0') THEN '' ELSE 'Mismatch' END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` expressions will always take the *first* `WHEN` clause that is `true`. You can take advantage of this to simplify individual parts of the expression:

```
CASE 
   WHEN Loan_Type1 = 'D1' AND Loan_Type2 = 'D0' THEN ''
   WHEN Loan_Type1 <> Loan_Type2 THEN 'Mismatch'
   ELSE '' END
```

Or you can do this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN Loan_Type1 <> Loan_Type2 
      AND (Loan_Type1 <> 'D1' OR Loan_Type2 <> 'D0') THEN 'Mismatch'
   ELSE '' END
```